# scanning was resumed at next area A, item, level number

Tags: cobol, mainframe

I am getting compilation error for the variable I have defined in working storage section. please help me

```
        WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.                                        
        77  WS-FS1              PIC 9(02).                              
        77  WS-FS2              PIC 9(02).                              
        01  WS-EOF-SW           PIC X(01) VALUE 'N'.                    
            88-EOF-SW           VALUE 'Y'.                              
 S   "88-EOF-SW" WAS INVALID.  SCANNING WAS RESUMED AT THE NEXT AREA "A"   //Error msg
        ITEM, LEVEL-NUMBER, OR THE START OF THE                            //Error msg
            88-NOT-EOF-SW       VALUE 'N'.                              
 S   "88-NOT-EOF-SW" WAS INVALID.  SCANNING WAS RESUMED AT THE NEXT AREA   //Error msg
        "A" ITEM, LEVEL-NUMBER, OR THE START OF                            //Error msg

        PROCEDURE DIVISION.                                             
             OPEN INPUT INPUT-FILE.                                     
             OPEN OUTPUT OUTPUT-FILE.                                   
             PERFORM UNTIL EOF-SW                                       
 S   "EOF-SW" WAS NOT DEFINED AS A DATA-NAME.  THE STATEMENT WAS DISCARD  //Error msg
       ED.                                                              
                READ INPUT-FILE                                         
                AT END MOVE 'Y' TO WS-EOF-SW                            
                                                                        
                MOVE IN-ALL(3:3)  TO OUT-SYM                            
                MOVE IN-ALL(6:7)  TO OUT-POL                            
                MOVE IN-ALL(13:2) TO OUT-MOD                            
                MOVE IN-ALL(15:2) TO OUT-MCO                            
                MOVE IN-ALL(17:2) TO OUT-LOC                            
                END-READ
```

Comment: Looks like you want to `88 EOF-SW` - and in this case I highly suggest to also use `SET EOF-SW TO TRUE`.

Comment: @SimonSobisch thanks for the help, I have corrected it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
      88-EOF-SW           VALUE 'Y'.
```

There isn't a level number. Variable declarations require a level number.

Comment: Thanks @meat for the help, I have made correction in my code and it is working fine now.